# Un-archive ALL Gmail conversations/emails

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

As the title says.

How can I go about un-archiving all 700 (or so) conversations in my Gmail account?

The reason for this is I have around 2500 in my Gmail account, I decided to go back and sort all of this using all of Gmail's features, labels, important or not icon, archiving etc.

But I need to un-archive everything in order to be able to do stuff in a better way (I think).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Click the "All Mail" label
2. Click the checkbox at the top of the list to select all the visible conversations
3. At the top of the results should now be a message similar to

   [image: screen shot after selecting "all"]

   The "Select all..." bit is a link. Click it so that **all** conversations are now selected. (You'll get a message to that effect.)
4. Click the "Move to Inbox" button

*Et voilà!*

Comment: That does it, thanks! Perhaps an image of the select all blah blah conversations in All Mail? I had a little bit of trouble finding it since it doesn't stand out. :)

Comment: Screen shot added.

Comment: All Mail have Incoming outgoing drafts, bin etc hence is the suggested action OK? What if someone has 1000's of mail?

Comment: "All mail" in this case ignores Spam and Trash.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, no need to move everything back to the Inbox. Go to All Mail and assign labels to the conversations there.

The "archive" action should be thought of as nothing more than "remove the Inbox label" or "move from Inbox to All Mail". Everything you archived is visible from the All Mail folder along with other conversations you assigned labels to.